# How to calculate final size after multiple convolutions with same padding?

Tags: math, padding, convolution, stride

Given I have the following:

```
s: stride
k: kernel size
i: input size
n: number of times a convolution layer was performed
```

With the convolution layer having the following parameters:

```
input = [b, i, i, c] (with batch size b and channel size c)
padding = 'SAME'
stride = s
kernel_size = k
```

**Is there a mathematical way to calculate the final output size?**

I can do the following to programmatically calculate the final output size:

```
final_size = i
for _ in range(n):
    final_size = np.ceil(final_size / s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `ceil(ceil(x / n) / m) = ceil(x / (x * m))` (at least for integer n and m), so it should simply be `final_size = np.ceil(i / (s ** n))`.